# How do I provide a sample response for a read only property in an ASP.NET Web API help page?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, documentation-generation

I've got an ASP.NET Web API and I'm using the [ASP.NET Web API Help Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx) to automatically generate documentation for my API. Everything works well except for one property on my model that is read only. My model looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class EventViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProjectUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return MvcUrlHelper.BuildUrl(MvcUrlType.Project, new MvcUrlContent()
            {
                ProjectSlug = ProjectSlug,
                OrganizationDomain = OrganizationDomain,
                OrganizationSlug = OrganizationSlug
            });
        }
    }

    public string OrganizationSlug { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationDomain { get; set; }
    public string ProjectSlug { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error when it tries to generate the sample response for an action returning this model:

> An exception has occurred while using the formatter
>   'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type
>   'application/json'. Exception message: Error getting value from
>   'ProjectUrl' on 'WebApi.Models.EventViewModel'.

If I comment out the ProjectUrl property then the sample response generates fine. Any idea how to tell it to treat that property as a normal string, or better yet provide what the sample value should be for that property?